# Filter Has Many Through Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am new to RoR. I am building e-commerce website in which i have two models Products and Categories as follows:

```
Products : has_many :categories_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_products


Categories:   has_many :categories_products
  has_many :products, through: :categories_products

Categories_products: belongs_to: products, belongs_to: categories
```

My website has megamenu for categories . My intend is to click any one of those categories and get all products that belongs to it. So far I am only able to get category_id as i am using parameters to get category.

```
if params[:category]
  @categoryproducts = :category.products.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
else
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

On using above method

> undefined method `products' for :category:Symbol

I have searched online most of them saying to use join table. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: change `:category` to `Categories` or `:category.products` to `Categories_products`

Comment: can you please reiterate as categories_products will just give me product id and category_id

Comment: Also if i change :category then how will i get products without parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `category_id` is being passed in params, You can do something like this:

```
if params[:category_id]
  @products = Product.joins(:categories).where(
    categories: { id: params[:category_id] }
  ).all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
else
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: I did follow your code but got one error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.category_id: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "categories_products" ON "categories_products"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_products"."category_id" WHERE "products"."category_id" = '97' LIMIT ? OFFSET ?" Any recommendation.

Comment: Can you update schema for the tables products & categories ?

Comment: Ahh!! it worked i was using category in general as params and not category_id. But now it works.